# Angular snackbar not disappear

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

I tried to use angular material but no property works.

```
openSnackBar(message: string) {

this._snackBar.open(message), {
    duration: 300,
    horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,
    verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,
  }
```

What have I been trying

```
openSnackBar(message: string) {
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  this._snackBar.open(message), {
    duration: 300,
    horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,
    verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,
  }
})
```

}

snackbar shows up but doesn't disappear. It also ignores position settings.

Comment: it should not be done outside of the Angular change detection, you are moving it in the zone, that's the reason it doesn't disappear, because the snack bar instance is out of change detection cycle. Try working with 1st option what is the error you are getting in that ?

Comment: check the example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-snackbar-example

Comment: the problem is that I don't get any error: / but I'll check again and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-snackbar-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbasic-snackbar%2Fbasic-snackbar.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: it's `open(message,,{duration: 300,..})`. See that the message and the configuration are both arguments of the method open